# call query in component A but result should show in Component B possible?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have two components:

```
SearchHeader
SearchMain
```

In SearchHeader I have a search Input and on every text that changes I want to display the Results in SearchMain. Is that possible ? If yes which function/ way I have to use ?

Should I create a Slice only for the text field and then use useSelector in SearchMain ? Or is that too much ?